# C Code Errors Never seen them before

Tags: c, windows, jgrasp

So I'm attempting to make a basic program that displays three numbers then the user has to re-enter them to test their concentration. It might just be becuase of the compiler im using but it seems strange. Im getting parse errors in places that dont make sense to like at the return at the end of main. Heres the errors:

```
----jGRASP exec: gcc -g -o Concentration.exe Concentration.c

Concentration.c: In function `main':
Concentration.c:28: error: parse error before "cYesNo"
Concentration.c: At top level:
Concentration.c:53: error: parse error before string constant
Concentration.c:53: warning: conflicting types for built-in function `printf'
Concentration.c:53: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Concentration.c:54: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Concentration.c:55: error: parse error before "return"

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
```

Also here's the code: The file is called Concetraion.c btw.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GYmhefDE — marked private and hence inaccessible

Mediafire Download: http://www.mediafire.com/view/kf73fzfsifqfuzj

Trimmed of comments, but hardly yet an MCVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
   char cYesNo = 'z';
   int guessNum1 = 0;
   int guessNum2 = 0, guessNum3 = 0;
   int randNuml = 0, randNum2 = 0, randNum3 = 0;
   int elapsedTime = 0;
   int currentTime = 0;
   int counter = 0;
   srand(time(NULL));

   printf("Play a game of Concentration? (y or n): ");
   scanf("%c", &cYesNo);

   if(cYesNo == 'y' cYesNo == 'Y')  // Line 28
   {
      randNuml = rand() % 100;
      randNum2 = rand() % 100;
      randNum3 = rand() % 100;
      printf("\nConcentrate on the next three numbers\n");
      printf("\n\t%d %d %d\n\n", randNuml , randNum2, randNum3);

      currentTime = time(NULL);

      do{
         elapsedTime = time(NULL);
      }while ((elapsedTime - currentTime) < 3);

      system("cls");

      printf("\nEnter each # separated with one space: ");
      scanf("%d%d%d", &guessNum1, &guessNum2, &guessNum3);

      if(randNuml == guessNum1 && randNum2 == guessNum2 && randNum3 == guessNum3)
         printf("\nCongratulations!\n");
      else
         printf("\nSorry, correct numbers were: %d %d %d\n", randNuml, randNum2, randNum3);
   }
   printf("\nPress any key to quit");  // Line 53
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pastebin says: "This is a private paste.  Please login to see it."

Comment: Paste your code here! Without the code this question will get worthless when your links die.

Comment: @librik: yeah .. the [Help Center](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help) says "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem".

Answer (score 3):

What is the first error?

> error: parse error before "cYesNo"

Does this look right to you?

`if(cYesNo == 'y' cYesNo == 'Y')`

Try adding an OR

`if(cYesNo == 'y' || cYesNo == 'Y')`

Comment: And I think the second error is caused by the compiler getting confused by the first, and misinterpreting the `}` at the end of the `if` block as 'end of function'.  The general rule of thumb is "if the second error doesn't make sense, fix the first and see whether that fixes the second".  If the second error does makes sense, then fix that too — but if the compiler gets confused, subsequent error messages are not necessarily very reliable, even with modern compilers (though compilers are much better now than they were 20-30 years ago).

Comment: Exactly. If you have written invalid code then any subsequent errors could be meaningless. Always fix the first error first.